# Using page template as Static Front Page

Tags: page-template, frontpage

I've created a page named "homepage", set the page as front page from `Reading > Static Page > Front page` and it's nearly working fine. The issue I'm having the blog posts aren't included into the page. It comes with the blank page and I need to change order as "menu_order", not working.

In other words, I need to get the pages in order as same as the navigation.

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * Template Name: One
 */

get_header();

$pages = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

foreach($pages as $_post) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $_post->post_content);
    $title = $_post->post_title;
    $slug = $_post->post_name;
    ?>

-div class content-

<?php
}
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The previous title didn't make sense. But I'm not sure I've captured the issue in the new one. What does not work:  **blog posts not showing** or **pages not in the correct order**?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to display your blog posts then you need to either change the front page reading option to latest posts then use either index.php or create a new file named front-page.php.

If you want your page query ordered by menu_order you need to add `'orderby' => 'menu_order'` to the query.

Comment: First of all, than you for the answer. Secondly, when I change the front page settings, I can view the blog post but can't view other pages. What I need to view both blog posts and pages at the front page.
By the way, navigation issue still persists. Current navigation order is :services/about/portfolio/contact/blog but what i get after adding the code you've suggested is :about/contact/blog/services/portfolio

Comment: Bump? Anyone? Bump?